# reading the file and save the details to database in php

Tags: php, mysql, file

i have a project from my school an attendance system and i got textfile contains with these elements:

```
2042 2018-03-08 17:03:25 27 0 15 0
26059 2018-03-08 17:04:30 27 0 15 0
259 2018-03-08 17:04:34 27 0 15 0
240 2018-03-08 17:05:20 27 1 15 0
26152 2018-03-08 17:05:26 27 1 15 0
152 2018-03-08 17:05:28 27 1 15 0
24073 2018-03-08 17:06:05 27 1 15 0
263 2018-03-08 17:08:12 27 1 15 0
2194 2018-03-08 17:08:27 27 1 15 0
26116 2018-03-08 17:09:47 27 1 15 0
2616 2018-03-08 17:09:51 27 1 15 0
```

now this textfile represents as fields with `id - date - time - and ignore the other lines`.

what would be the best option to cater with this situation?

i tried this option, but in my database, sometimes i failed to get the ID because it has different id string lengths . Please help me to improve my code, where i tried this one:

```
$lines = file(base_url()."./assets/uploads/".$filename);
                while (!feof($lines)){ 
                    preg_match("'^(.{10})(.{2})(.*)$'",$lines,$n);
                    $data3 = array(
                        'id' => trim(substr($lines, 1,8)),
                        'time' => trim(substr($lines, 20, 9)),
                        'desig_date' =>  trim(substr($lines, 9, 11)),
                        'file' => $filename
                    );
                    $this->Attendance->savedata($data3);
                }
```

Comment: Try looking at `fgetcsv()` using space as the delimiter

Comment: @NigelRen but my file is not a csv file

Comment: It looks like a delimited file, agreed not with commas, but if you use spaces as a delimiter the overall result should be the same.